# Are there open-source WAF solutions?

Tags: kubernetes, open-source, web-application-firewall

I am looking for an open-source WAF solution that could be deployed in Kubernetes. I've looked a ModSecurity but it seems like good rules cost money and it also requires lots of tuning.

Answer (score 3):

> it seems like good rules cost money and it also requires lots of tuning

How can you define the "good rules"?

There are "good rules" in my opinion, called [CoreRuleSet](https://coreruleset.org), it's absolutely free. And I don't think you need to tune it too much. CRS has a good [community](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset), you can ask anything. Its development is very active.

I think you should take a look.

Beside ModSecurity, there is a new competitor, called [Coraza](https://coraza.io/). It also uses SecLang format for the configuration, and it's 100% compatible with CRS.

Comment: Well, good is about coverage and about false positives. CRS seems to require lots of tuning, I don't have the time for this. As for coverage, I guess there's a reason why AWS, F5 and others are selling rules.

Comment: You are concerning about FP's - but what about FN's (false negatives)? You should take a look to this article (2 parts, the next in the article): https://blog.fraktal.fi/cloud-waf-comparison-using-real-world-attacks-acb21d37805e. F5 is not a competitor there, but as you can see, CRS is a very good rule set.

Comment: coraza with the stable plugin for https://caddyserver.com/ looks like a good choice to run in rootless podman